# Scrollable sidebar with full height main with tailwind

Tags: css, user-interface, frontend, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a scrollable sidebar with a full-height main using Tailwind.
I tried using the overflow but it doesn't work. I only want to make the **ul** scrollable, the others should have the full height of the page.

```
 <div class="flex h-full w-full flex-col">
  <!-- Website -->
  <header class="bg-neutral-300">Header</header>
  <div class="flex flex-1 gap-5">
    <!-- Sidebar and main -->
    <aside class="flex w-1/6 items-center">
      <ul class="flex flex-col gap-10 overflow-auto bg-red-300 text-sm">
        <li>List Item 1</li>
        <li>List Item 2</li>
        <li>List Item 3</li>
        <li>List Item 4</li>
        <li>List Item 5</li>
        <li>List Item 6</li>
        <li>List Item 7</li>
        <li>List Item 8</li>
        <li>List Item 9</li>
        <li>List Item 10</li>
        <li>List Item 11</li>
        <li>List Item 12</li>
        <li>List Item 13</li>
        <li>List Item 14</li>
        <li>List Item 15</li>
        <li>List Item 16</li>
        <li>List Item 17</li>
        <li>List Item 18</li>
        <li>List Item 19</li>
        <li>List Item 20</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="bg-red-600 p-2 text-xs">arrow to toggle sidebar</div>
    </aside>
    <main class="flex-1 overflow-hidden bg-green-300">This is main</main>
  </div>
</div>

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider applying `min-height: 0` to the second `<div>` element to override the implicit `min-height: min-content`. Then, apply `max-height: 100%` to the `<ul>` so that it does not overflow the container. This will mean the **content** of the `<ul>` will overflow, making it scrollable.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="flex h-full w-full flex-col">
  <!-- Website -->
  <header class="bg-neutral-300">Header</header>
  <div class="flex flex-1 gap-5 min-h-0">
    <!-- Sidebar and main -->
    <aside class="flex w-1/6 items-center">
      <ul class="flex flex-col gap-10 overflow-auto bg-red-300 text-sm max-h-full">
        <li>List Item 1</li>
        <li>List Item 2</li>
        <li>List Item 3</li>
        <li>List Item 4</li>
        <li>List Item 5</li>
        <li>List Item 6</li>
        <li>List Item 7</li>
        <li>List Item 8</li>
        <li>List Item 9</li>
        <li>List Item 10</li>
        <li>List Item 11</li>
        <li>List Item 12</li>
        <li>List Item 13</li>
        <li>List Item 14</li>
        <li>List Item 15</li>
        <li>List Item 16</li>
        <li>List Item 17</li>
        <li>List Item 18</li>
        <li>List Item 19</li>
        <li>List Item 20</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="bg-red-600 p-2 text-xs">arrow to toggle sidebar</div>
    </aside>
    <main class="flex-1 overflow-hidden bg-green-300">This is main</main>
  </div>
</div>
```